# Laptop with power problems now with unresponsive keys

Tags: laptop, keyboard, hardware-failure, power, hp-elitebook

I became an owner of an HP EliteBook 8460p recently and had an issue where the power button wouldn't work for turning on the computer. I use the "QuickWeb" button which can turn on the computer and access QuickWeb. I installed Windows 10 so it no longer has this software and just turns on the computer normally.

The computer can't be turned on back from hibernation/sleep mode, and has to be cut out from power in order to turn it back on. I don't mind much this problem but now the problem that I have is the 1,2,3,8,9,0,F,G,J keys suddenly no longer work.

I have disconnected the keyboard, cleaned what I could and reconnected it, but the problem still persists. I've tried some online solutions that involve changing Ease of Access settings, uninstalling the driver, as well as changing registry keys, without any success. The problem is also present in Ubuntu, making me think it's hardware related.

My worry is not knowing if the keyboard problem is related to the power problem, I'd like to buy a new keyboard if they're not related and buying a new one will solve it.

Comment: The keyboard and power problems seem unrelated, but that machine has a lot of problems.

Comment: I'm stuck with this until I can get a better one in the middle of the year.